# Make a 2D array of circles with a distance of 2 radius from each centers

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am currently working on making an NxN arrays of circles where N>0 with varying circle radius inside a 1024 by 1024 meshgrid. The n_circles defines the number of circles in an array, and R is the radius. I used a repmat function to replicate the array  depending  on the number of circles I choose. Here's my code below:

```
n_circles = 4                    % Define the number of circles to be plotted                               
n0 = round(1024/n_circles); % Define the size of the basic mask
M0 = zeros(n0);             % Initialize the basic mask
I = 1:n0;             % Define the x and y coordinates of the basic mask
x = I - n0/2;
y = n0/2 - I;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);      % Create the mask
R = 4;                      % Define the radius of the basic circle

% Get the indices of the points inside the basic circle
A = (X.^2 + Y.^2 <= R^2);   
M0(A) = 1;                           % Set basic mask
% Replicate basic mask according to the number of circles to be plotted
M=repmat(M0,n_circles,n_circles); 
M(2^10,2^10) = 0;                    % zerofill the rest of the matrix

figure(1)
imagesc(M)
daspect([1 1 1])

imwrite(M,[num2str(n_circles),'array.bmp'])
```

The problem is that the circles are not touching each other, i.e. when I replicate them, they are far away from each other. I need to generate a 2D array of circles that are touching from each other, with the radius set at low values. I attached a picture below to visualize my concern.

[image]

So in the picture, the circles have a distance of 2 radii from their centers, and the radius of the circle is very small in such a way that the whole 2D array of circles is smaller than the whole meshgrid. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you define touch? If you don't mean overlap, then it may be a matter of image resolution where the point of contact between two circles is not clear. Moreover you could consider the alignment of the centres of the circles.

Comment: Can you sum up what you are attempting to do into a single question? Since the beginning of february, both SO and Mahworks Forum have been filled with questions concerning your repeated circles. This gives me the impression that your development is painful and you are struggling a lot with this, and I would really like to help you out.

Comment: Hi Tommaso Belluzzo,

Thank you for the  concern. What I'm trying to achieve is to make a program that generates 2D array of circular apertures in a 2^10 meshgrid in which I can also vary N, the number of circles in an array, and R, the radius of the circle. Also, ,the circles are 2 radii apart from their centers. And when I say apertures, it means the size of a single circle should really be small relative to the meshgrid. I'll be propagating  coherent light in the generated result and observe the diffraction patterns. Smaller apertures give wider ad better  diffraction patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Step 1**: we create a "mask" and get the indexes of the point of it. Note that we save it as `[xx,yy]` by calling `ind2sub`, so `[x0+xx-R,y0+yy-R]` will be the indexes of a circle with the center `[x0,y0]`.
- **Step 2**: Figuring out the center of a circle, we could call `sub2ind(size(M),MidX+xx-R,MidY+yy-R)` to get real indexes of it.*(It seems pretty strange but I only got this way, waiting for better answers.)*
- **Step 3**: Using a `for` loop to generate all the circles in the `M`.

Note that if `n_circle` is **odd**, we should do some math and move the centers of the circle a little to keep all the circles in the middle of the picture.

---

```
clc; clear;
n_circles = 4;                    % Define the number of circles to be plotted
R = 4;                      % Define the radius of the basic circle
Len=400;
M=zeros(Len);               % Create the hole mask

% Get the indices of the points inside the basic circle
M0 = zeros(2*R+1);             % Initialize the basic mask
I = 1:(2*R+1);             % Define the x and y coordinates of the basic mask
x = (I - R)-1;
y = (R - I)+1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);      % Create the mask
A = (X.^2 + Y.^2 <= R^2);   
[xx,yy]=ind2sub(size(M0),find(A == true)); 


%plot
for ii=1:n_circles
    for jj=1:n_circles
      MidX=Len/2+(ii-n_circles/2-0.5)*(2*R);
      MidY=Len/2+(jj-n_circles/2-0.5)*(2*R);
%       [MidX MidY]
      M(sub2ind(size(M),MidX+xx-R-1,MidY+yy-R-1))=1;
    end
end
figure(1)
imshow(M)
```

The output image is:

[image]

*hope it helps!*